# cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d243.dll'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm tryong to run a cpp program in VS 2010 and openCV 2.4.3 and I got the following error after settings all the necessary :
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d243.dll'

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

add the bin file address of OpenCV to the environmental settings path of your system...

Comment: Hi, I am new in VS and openCV but I did this but could you just briefly summarise the way to do it perhaps i missed something.

Comment: right click my computer...properties...advanced system settings....advanced tab....environmental vsriables...system variables....select "path"....add the address eg.. C:\opencv\build\bin

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is copy the dll to the directory from you run the application, and inside of vs2010 set the working diretory in the project to this path.

Comment: Hi, sorry for this stupid question but you mean what by working directory?

Comment: You mean the path where to save the project? or the path where the includes exist?